# I need to get a substring from a java string Tokenizer

Tags: java, string, netbeans, substring, tokenize

I need to get a substring from a java string tokenizer.

My inpunt string is = Pizza-1*Nutella-20*Chicken-65*

```
        StringTokenizer productsTokenizer = new StringTokenizer("Pizza-1*Nutella-20*Chicken-65*", "*");
        do
        {
            try
            {
                int pos = productsTokenizer .nextToken().indexOf("-");
                String product = productsTokenizer .nextToken().substring(0, pos+1);
                String count= productsTokenizer .nextToken().substring(pos, pos+1);
                System.out.println(product + "   " + count);
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
        while(productsTokenizer .hasMoreTokens());
```

My output must be:

```
Pizza  1
Nutella  20
Chicken  65
```

I need the product value and the count value in separate variables to insert that values in the Data Base.

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Why don't you simply replace `*` and `-` with a space?

Comment: You really shouldn't be using `StringTokenizer`, as the Javdocs for it state.

Comment: @MarounMaroun no, because i need the product and the count in separate variables, after i have to insert that values to the DB.

Comment: Not sure if you're familiar with regular expressions, but this is a good application for them.  Check out my answer if you're interested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `String.split()` as

```
String[] products = "Pizza-1*Nutella-20*Chicken-65*".split("\\*");

for (String product : products) {
    String[] prodNameCount = product.split("\\-");
    System.out.println(prodNameCount[0] + " " + prodNameCount[1]);
}
```

***Output***

```
Pizza  1
Nutella  20
Chicken  65
```

Answer (score 0):

You invoke the nextToken() method 3 times. That will get you 3 different tokens

```
int pos = productsTokenizer .nextToken().indexOf("-");
String product = productsTokenizer .nextToken().substring(0, pos+1);
String count= productsTokenizer .nextToken().substring(pos, pos+1);
```

Instead you should do something like:

```
String token = productsTokenizer .nextToken();
int pos = token.indexOf("-");
String product = token.substring(...);
String count= token.substring(...);
```

I'll let you figure out the proper indexes for the substring() method.

Also instead of using a do/while structure it is better to just use a while loop:

```
while(productsTokenizer .hasMoreTokens())
{
    // add your code here
}
```

That is don't assume there is a token.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative answer you may want to use if your input grows:

```
// find all strings that match START or '*' followed by the name (matched),
// a hyphen and then a positive number (not starting with 0)
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:^|[*])(\\w+)-([1-9]\\d*)");
Matcher finder = p.matcher(products);
while (finder.find()) {
    // possibly check if the new match directly follows the previous one
    String product = finder.group(1);
    int count = Integer.valueOf(finder.group(2));
    System.out.printf("Product: %s , count %d%n", product, count);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Some people dislike regex, but this is a good application for them.  All you need to use is `"(\\w+)-(\\d{1,})\\*"` as your pattern.  Here's a toy example:

```
    String template = "Pizza-1*Nutella-20*Chicken-65*";
    String pattern = "(\\w+)-(\\d+)\\*";

    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(template);

    while(m.find())
    {
        System.out.println(m.group(1) + " " + m.group(2)); 
    }
```

To explain this a bit more, `"(\\w+)-(\\d+)\\*"` looks for a `(\\w+)`, which is any set of at least 1 character from `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, followed by a `-`, followed by a number `\\d+`, where the`+` means at least one character in length, followed by a `*`, which must be escaped.  The parentheses capture what's inside of them.  There are two sets of capturing parentheses in this regex, so  we reference them by `group(1)` and `group(2)` as seen in the `while` loop, which prints:

```
Pizza 1
Nutella 20
Chicken 65
```